# How to display location in a custom indoor map, given the coordinates X,Y

Tags: android

I want to create a map for an indoor location finding App. I have images of the building layouts and how they should look, but I don't know how to show the exact location given some coordinates (X,Y). I only need something simple.

I'm creating an indoor location finding app, based on WiFi signals. The algorithm part returns a pair of coordinates (X,Y), and I want to display the location somehow.

I really don't know how I should do this. 
My first thoughts were to get the pixel coordinates of the (0,0) point on the image, and the distance in pixels between two points, i.e (0,0) and (0,1), (I know they are equidistant). The image, the pixel coordinates and distance are stored in an object.

Now, given a pair (X,Y) the object above, I can calculate on which pixel the location should fall on. But this isn't MATLAB, and I'm not sure how to edit it or if I can add a Pin or something on top of the image in order to show the location.

Example: 
Here is an image of a building
[image: The image of a building]

I know for the point (0,0)(starting from bottom left)  pixel coords are (47,223) and the distance between the points is 45px.

Given the coordinates (1,2.5), I have to show the estimated location. Which is the pixel (92,110) and have to highlight it somehow.

[image: The image of a building with the estimated location]

This is my only idea, as I'm pretty new to Android developement. It doesn't necessarily have to be like this, I just want to pinpoint a location given a pair of coords (X,Y).  I'm open to suggestions.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: in android, screen coordinates start from top-left.